# Deleting a row from a data set

Tags: r, loops, while-loop, dataset

I am trying to create a function that deletes `n` rows from a data set in R. The rows that I want to delete are the minimum values from the column `time` in the data set `my_data_set`.

I currently have

```
delete_data <- function(n)
{
  k=1
  while(k <= n) 
  {
    my_data_set = my_data_set[-(which.min(my_data_set$time)),]
    k=k+1
  }
}
```

When I input these lines manually (without the use of the `while` loop) it works perfectly but I am not able to get the loop to work.

I am calling the function by:

```
delete_data(n = 2)
```

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
my_data_set[ ! my_data_set$time == min(my_data_set$time),  ]
```

Or if you are using data.table and wish to use the more direct syntax that data.table provides:

```
library(data.table)
setDT( my_data_set ) 

my_data_set[ ! time == min(time) ]
```

Then review how `R` work.  R is a vectorized language that pretty much does what you mean without having to resort to complicated loops.

Answer (score 0):

Also try:

```
my_data_set <- my_data_set[which(my_data_set$time > min(my_data_set$time)),]
```

By the way, `which.min()` will only pick up the first record if there is more than one record matching the minimum value.